# Integral ring extension (Problem with quotient rings)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $A$ and $B$ rings such that $A\subset B$ is an integral ring extension.

$\textbf{Proposition.-}$ If $J$ is an ideal of $B$ and $J\cap A =I$, then $\dfrac{A}{I}\subset \dfrac{B}{J}$ is an integral ring extension.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ (One I found)
Let $b+J\in \dfrac{B}{J}$, then $b\in B$. Since $A\subset B$ is an integral ring extension,
$\implies b^n+a_1b^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}b+a_n=0\hspace{1cm}$ for some $a_i\in A$
$\implies (b^n+a_1b^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}b+a_n)+J=J\hspace{1cm}(J=0_\frac{B}{J})$
$\implies (b^n+J)+(a_1b^{n-1}+J)+...+(a_{n-1}b+J)+(a_n+J)=J\hspace{1cm}(\Delta)$
$\implies (b+J)^n+(a_1+I)(b+J)^{n-1}+...+(a_{n-1}+I)(b+J)+(a_n+I)=J\hspace{0.5cm}$ where each $a_i+I\in \frac{A}{I}\hspace{0.5cm}(\Delta\Delta)$

Therefore, $\dfrac{A}{I}\subset \dfrac{B}{J}$ is an integral ring extension.

The problem is, I don't get how the line with $(\Delta)$ implies the line with $(\Delta\Delta)$ (How does the $I$ appear).
And is this correct $(a_1b^{n-1}+J)=(a_1+I)(b+J)^{n-1}$ ? I don't see how.

Comment: The notation in this proposed proof is a bit sloppy. The basic point is that because $J \cap A = I$, the composition of the inclusion $A \to B$ with the canonical quotient morphism $B \to B/J$ has kernel $I$, and so descends to an injective map $A/I \to B/J$. The proof is implicitly appealing to the resulting $A/I$-module structure on $B/J$ - they write $a_{i} + I$ when they really mean the (injective) image of $a_{i} + I$ in $B/J$. (Of course, injectivity is not so important here, but it does justify regarding elements of $A/I$ as elements of $B/J$ by viewing $A/I$ as a subring of $B/J$.)